# Best practice for near reuse of model components?

Tags: language-agnostic, oop

I have a requirement to use a `Fund` model in my code.  It will contain a fund name and fund code.  In the interest of reuse I've poked around the package containing the other models used and found an existing `Fund` model.  However the issue here is that, in addition to fund name and code, it also contains an amount.  Amount isn't directly relevant in my context.  So, do I:

1) Use the existing `Fund` model as is, ignoring the setters/getters for fund amount.

2) Put a `FundDescription` interface onto the existing `Fund` model for accessing only the information I'm interested in.

3) Make a `FundDescription` base class from which the existing `Fund` model could now extend

4) Create a whole new seperate model since the two are slightly contextually different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1** could confuse a person that reads the code, and could tempt someone who doesn't understand your code fully, to use those setters/getters due to some misunderstanding. The other options sort of forces him to understand your code better.

**Option 2** Sort of second-place-solution but to me it wouldn't make perfect sense logically.

**Option 3** It is the cleanest and most logical way of solving the problem among those listed, and I would say that that qualifies as close to best practice in this case.

**Option 4** This sounds unnecessary! :-)

**Option 5** (NEW! The one I'd go for :-)  Have a member variable of type `FundDescriptor` in the `Fund` model.

Whenever faced with this kind of design decisions I usually try to avoid thinking "what would be the most efficient solution" or "what would be the solution requiring least code", but instead think of **what would look most logical to for a person that reads the code for the first time**.

Think of the "extends" construct as an "is-a" relation, and read it out loud. If it makes sense and is logical, go for it. How does, "a `Fund` *is a* `FundDescriptor`" sound to you? If it sounds like "hmm.. that doesn't make sense", then I'd go for option 5, otherwise I would go for option 3.

Have a look at the accepted answer at

[Inheritance vs. Aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269496/inheritance-vs-aggregation)

Comment: Nice answer.  Thanks.  I like your option 5.