# need help with object oriented program in Visual C++

Tags: c++

guys, I have the following code, but I'm getting error at compiling time... the error is at the end. Thanks
1st Class is "Person"

```
#ifndef PERSON_H//protecting .h files
#define PERSON_H//protecting .h files
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Person
{
public:
    Person();
    Person(string first, string last)
    {
        firstName = first;
        lastName = last;
    }
    virtual void setName(string first, string last)
    {
        firstName = first;
        lastName = last;
    }
    virtual void setWeightAge(int w, int a)
    {
        weight = w;
        age = a;
    }
    virtual string getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }
    virtual string getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }
    virtual int getWeight()
    {
        return weight;
    }
    virtual int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }
    virtual void printPerson()
    {
        cout << "Name: " << firstName << " " << lastName << endl;
        cout << "Age: " << age << endl;
        cout << "Weight: " << weight << endl;
    }
protected:
    string firstName, lastName;
    int weight, age;
};
#endif
```

2nd Class is "Student"

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H//protecting .h files
#define STUDENT_H//protecting .h files
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Person.h"
using namespace std;

class Student : public Person
{
public: 
    Student();
    Student(Person s)
    {
        sStudent = s;
    }
    virtual void setGPA(double g)
    {
        gpa = g;
    }
    virtual void setSchedule(string c, string t, string d)
    {
        stClass = c;
        time = time;
        days = d;
    }
    virtual void setGrade(char g)
    {
        grade = g;
    }
    virtual double getGPA()
    {
        if (grade == 'a') { gpa = 4.0; }
        if (grade == 'b') { gpa = 3.0; }
        if (grade == 'c') { gpa = 2.0; }
        else gpa = 0;
        return gpa;
    }
    virtual char getGrade()
    {
        return grade;
    }

    virtual void printSchedule()
    {
        cout << "Class | Days | Time " << endl;
        cout << stClass << " | " << days << " | " << time << endl;
    }
protected:
    string stClass, time, days;
    char grade;
    double gpa;
    Person sStudent;
};
#endif
```

and Main()

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Student.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //creating a person
    Person john("John", "Smith");
    john.setWeightAge(180, 39);
    john.printPerson();

    //making john a student
    Student johnStdntMath(john);
    johnStdntMath.setSchedule("Math", "7:45", "M, W");
    johnStdntMath.setGrade('b');
    johnStdntMath.printPerson();
    johnStdntMath.printSchedule();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
```

errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Person, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Person::Person(void)" (??0Person@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Student::Student(class Person)" (??0Student@@QAE@VPerson@@@Z)
1>c:\users\jorge\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Person\Debug\Person.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
}
```

Comment: Why have you made all of the functions virtual?  Does it actually make sense to allow a derived class to override the implementation of `getFirstName` or `setName`?

Comment: Is this Visual Studio? What version is this? The error message is awful, it barely speaks proper C++.

Comment: @wilhelmtell:  Maybe I'm too used to programming in C++, but I think the error is pretty good.  It names the function for which it can't find a definition and tells you where the definition was needed.  It even helpfully demangles the name for you.  I'm not sure what other information the linker has available that it could give you.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis It's not missing information, on the contrary, it's perfectly alright on that front. But `Person::Person(void)`? `Student::Student(class Person)`? What sort of dialect is that? :p

Comment: @wilhelmtell:  Well, the former is perfectly valid.  In the latter, it is (I presume) attempting to be helpful by telling you that `Person` is a class type.  I don't know for sure, I've never paid that much attention to this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't implement the default constructor `Person()`,you can write it like this:

```
Person():weight(0)
        ,age(0){};
```

If you just want to complier it, this is enough;
Here are some tips below:
1.Check your mind, does class `Student` really need a `Person` member. If you really need it, `Student(Person)` may add an `explicit` symbol:

```
explicit Student(const Person& s) : sStudent(s) {...};
```

2.In `Person.h`

```
  protected:
        string firstName, lastName;
        int weight, age;
```

the `protected` may be `private`?

Comment: I have done code before that the constructor does not initialize any variables... why in this case needed to initialize those variables?

Comment: Constructor is used for giving the member a proper initialization.For the constructor with params,the params usually is used for initializing the member:`Person(int w, int a):weight(w),age(a){}`. For the default Constructor, you need to initialize the member too: `Person():weight(0),age(0){}`.In this case, `firstName` and `lastName` is initialized to `""` while `weight` and `age` are `0`. You may ask why `firstName` is `""`? Because the `string` Class has default initialized it, but `int` type hasn't,so we give it a value `0`:`weight(0)`. Overall, give every member a proper value when coding!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you double check your is-A and has-A relationships.

Writing `Student : public Person` says that a Student is-A Person. But later, you have a member variable `sStudent` of type `Person`, which says a Student has-A Person, and I'm guessing is not what you really want.

Check out the answers to this question: [Inheritance vs. Aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269496/inheritance-vs-aggregation) for better explanations.

Comment: That's a good point and true. I'm going to suggest a variation on that in my answer. +1

Comment: yeah, you're right no need to pass a Person object as a parameter to a student constructor... once I create the student object I can use setName function from Person class... but there are instances where an object is pass as a parameter or by reference... could you point out a case

Answer (score 1):

Listen to your linker, it's just as it says: In constructor `Student::Student(Person)` you're referring to constructor `Person::Person()`, but you didn't define `Person::Person()`, not in a way the linker can see when it does its thing with the `Student` constructor.

Technically, because you are filling in `sStudent` in the `Student` constructor's body the compiler first default-initializes the `Person` object `sStudent`, and then *assigns* to it `s`, the `Person` parameter of the constructor. If you'd use the initializer list then the `Person` member wouldn't be default-initialized and then assigned to but rather copy-constructed right away:

```
Student(const Person& s) : sStudent(s) { }
```

But the question remains: Why are you publicly declaring a default constructor in `Person` and not define it?

Also, you have a leak in `Student`. The `string` and `Person` members of `Student` won't clean up because when a `Student` object destructs its destructor won't be called. The `Person` destructor will be called, but not the `Student` destructor, and the reason being that the destructor of `Person` is non-virtual.

One more thing: It's a bad idea in object-oriented design in general and C++ in particular to use inheritance for reuse. The reason is that this very often leads to a violation of the [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). It can also bear a (not major but nonetheless) performance overhead for introducing a virtual table. But it's the correctness that suffers that matters when you pick inheritance when you should really be using delegation.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the *no argument* constructor for `Person` when you create the `johnStdntMath` instance.  You need to either

1. Implement `Person::Person()` or ...
2. Change `Student::Student(Person s)` to `Student::Student(Person const& s)`

There are some other problems in your code as well.  `Student` [*is-a*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isa_%28computer_science%29) `Person` so there is no need for the `Student` class to have a `Person` member variable - it shares the instance variables of its base class by virtue of inheritance.  In other words, `Student` extends `Person` so your program could be written:

```
int main() {
    Student johnStdntMath;
    johnStdntMath.setName("John", "Smith")
    johnStdntMath.setWeightAge(180, 39);
    johnStdntMath.setSchedule("Math", "7:45", "M, W");
    johnStdntMath.setGrade('b');
    johnStdntMath.printPerson();
    johnStdntMath.printSchedule();
    return 0;
}
```

I would also avoid the `using namespace std;` statement anywhere and especially in a header file.  For example, your `Student` class contains a member variable named `time`.  This will conflict with the `std::time_t std::time(std::time_t*)` function defined in `<ctime>` if that header is included before `"student.h"`.

Comment: no, no homework... can you tell the resemblance to java programming?