# I need to understand composition and inheritance better

Tags: oop, inheritance, polymorphism, composition

I have a baseball player super class

I have a left field, center field, right field, 3b, ss, 2b, 1b, catcher, pitcher that inherits from player.

So, let's take the pitchers for example. Would a pitcher class be a super class inheriting from baseball player too? with starter, reliever, setup, closer being classes that inherits from pitcher AND baseball player class?

Would my pitchers arsenal be an interface?  for example, fast ball, curveball, slider, changeup?

let's say we have a new instance of pitcher called nolan, would nolan's fast ball be a 'composition' since nolan's fast ball relies on nolan, or in other words or doesn't exist without him?

I'm stuck on composition..can someone shed some light following the baseball analogy..

Comment: The example is a bit strange, not everybody knows about baseball...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inheritance vs. Aggregation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269496/inheritance-vs-aggregation)

Comment: You might consider giving this book a read: [The Object Oriented Thought Process](http://www.amazon.com/Object-Oriented-Thought-Process-Matt-Weisfeld/dp/0672330164/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1339893585&sr=1-1&keywords=object+oriented+thought+process)

Comment: Thanks Nick. I'm checking it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put this is simple terms, inheritance is an *is-a* relationship, while composition is a *has-a* relatiohship.

A pitcher *is* a baseball player, so a pitcher would inherit from a baseball player. Also, a pitcher *has* an arsenal of pitches, so that could be defined as composition, although aggregation may be more appropriate if pitchers have varying pitches that they use, as aggregation includes lists.

Comment: my followup to that is, does nolan have to have ownership of the arsenal? such as, nolan's 97mph fastball rather then a generic 91mph fastball? I mean this in the way of existence, like he is throwing the pitch..does that make sense?

Comment: Nolan will have specific information that is not relevant to all pitchers, so he will most likely have a fastball by composition or aggregation.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help. So if something can exist after it's creator dies, that would be a form of aggregation? If it died with the creator, that would be composition? Please forgive me, I'm close to understanding I think. Since nolan throws a fastball (even tho it is HIS fastball), that fastball can still exist without nolan or aka aggregation. is that correct? Or would it be because it is HIS fastball that stops existing after he throws it, it is a composition?

Comment: If a fastball is a class, then Nolan will have an instance of that class, which will die when he does. The only difference between composition and aggregation is that composition means one item per parent, but aggregation is many items per parent.

Comment: Thanks, I'm on board with you now. Finally, would you give an example of what an aggregation would be for this analogy of the pitcher and the pitches?

Comment: Say one pitcher uses a fastball, curveball, and changeup, and another pitcher uses a fastball, curveball, and slider. In this case, any pitcher is not guaranteed to have any given pitch. He only has a list of pitches that he uses. This would be aggregation, whereas composition would be having one of each pitch. It's a bit of a lame example, but the pitcher/pitches scenario isn't very conducive to good examples.

Comment: @KendallFrey An example for composition vs aggregation. A pitcher wears a (composition) baseball glove but he also has a collection (aggregation) of possible pitches to throw. Hope that helps.