# Is it a good practice to extend a zf2 controller twice?

Tags: model-view-controller, controller, zend-framework2

I Searched a lot to find the answer to this question, here on stackoverflow and over on google. But was not able to find anything...

So, my question is: It is a good practice to extend a controller (in my case BaseUserController from zfcuser) once in a module, and once more in another module?

Thanks for all your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine, I would not go as far as "good practice".

Excessive use of inheritance can cause you issues in any language and there are [numerous of post around explaining the issues and possible solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269496/inheritance-vs-aggregation).

From a ZF2 perspective in doing so you will have the issue where `Module B` depends on `Module A` which may be a problem - However this really depends your application/module design.

There are other alternatives:

- Aggregation -
  create new functionality by taking other classes and combining them into a new class. Attach an common interface to this new class for interoperability with other code.
- Use [PHP traits](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) - If you lucky enough to use the more recent versions of (PHP 5.4+) the you can simply reuse these within each controller class that requires it.
- A Custom [Controller Plugin](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html) - ZF2 has a "pluggable" API within the controller, meaning you can write self contained helper classes that can then be used in any controller - No need to extend. You are almost certainly using these already with `$this->redirect()` or `$this->params()` so they might be good places to start to see how they are built.

Comment: Thanks Alex! I want to extend only this controler twice! Thanks!