# Can I create a common class, just for a single variable and extend it. Or initialize that variable in each class and use it?

Tags: java, oop, junit, extends, errorcollector

I have a common variable `errorCollector`, and the 2 below approaches works for me.
But I cant figure out which is best or which is standard?

Approach 1 : Creating a common class for that variable then extending it.

```
class QAErrorCollector
{//This class is created only for this variable alone.
    @Rule
    public ErrorCollector errorCollector = new ErrorCollector();
}


class TestFeatureA extends QAErrorCollector
{

// use errorCollector
}

class TestFeatureB extends QAErrorCollector
{

// use errorCollector
}
```

Approach 2:  Creating 2 different variables for each class. (This approach will work too in test case)

```
class TestFeatureA
    {
        @Rule
        public ErrorCollector errorCollector = new ErrorCollector();

        // use errorCollector
    }

    class TestFeatureB
    {
         @Rule
        public ErrorCollector errorCollector = new ErrorCollector();

        // use errorCollector
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inheritance vs. Aggregation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269496/inheritance-vs-aggregation)

Comment: Do you want a new instance of `ErrorCollector` in each class, or would it be OK to use the same instance in each TestFeatureA, TestFeatureB, etc.?