# Limitation with classes derived from generic classes in swift

Tags: class, generics, swift

I'm trying to derive my class from generic class:

```
class foo<T> {}
class bar : foo<Int> {}
```

But this code fails to compile with en error:

> Classes derived from generic classes must also be generic

How to avoid this limitation? Is it possible?

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: So generic in swift is almost unusable

Comment: Not true, it just doesn't have the same design as generics in other languages.

Comment: @ssgreg, please see my "poor man's solution" to your problem.

Comment: @ssgreg I would have to agree this is very crippling.

Answer (score 23):

Ssreg,

Unfortunately this is [official](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/GenericParametersAndArguments.html):

> You can subclass a generic class, but the subclass must also be a
>   generic class.

Let us hope Apple fixes this in a future version.

Meanwhile, let us see this as an opportunity to exploit [aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269496/inheritance-vs-aggregation) instead of subclassing.

NOTE:

As a poor man's version of a solution, one could use `typealias`:

```
class foo<T> {}
class bar<Int> : foo<Int> {}
typealias Bar = bar<Int>
```

This way, the rest of the code can be written just as if Apple already fixed the matter.

Comment: You appear to be quoting the documentation, can you confirm this?  I cannot find that passage in your link (or under the Types section).  I wonder if they changed the docs and possibly intent.

Comment: Hey @chrisco, I just tried it in b6: no cigar, compiler complains.

Comment: Right, I noticed the same in B6.  But the documentation though - was that a direct quote, because I don't see that passage now?

Comment: Yes, I was a direct quote. And you're right, can't find it on the new doc... That's odd.

Comment: let's note that when you write      `class bar<Int> : foo<Int> {}`  the Int become a placeholder for the generic type, overriding the actual swift Int type. This will generate very funny error messages when you try to use the Int's properties inside the class.. It's better to use the hpique solution with unused generic type in the child class, and to bind the base class to the real Int type (or the desired one)

Comment: I don't believe this will work. Like @hariseldon78 says, Int is now a generic type. When I try `Bar<[MyClass]> : Foo<[MyClass]>` it complains about a missing "identifier to name generic parameter"

Comment: Instead I'm doing: `class bar<T:Int> : foo<Int> {}`

Answer (score 19):

I had the same issue and I found a solution!

```
class SomeType {
}
class Foo<T> {
}
class Bar<T: SomeType>: Foo<T> {
}
```

Now you can do:

```
let bar = Bar()
```

This will default Bar's type to SomeType. The only drawback is that you can only do this for 'subclassable' types. So for `Int` this will not work.

Comment: This does work, but has a slight code smell to it. Nice find.

Comment: Just wanted to build on your findings and suggest a possible edit.  I had success by building on your answer to declare a class `public final class NonGenericSubclass {}`, then building on your example above, I'd declare `Bar` like so: `class Bar<T : NonGenericSubclass> : Foo<Int> { ... }`.  This way, I get all the benefits of `Foo` typed to int, but I can still initialize as if `Bar` were not generic.  Also, because `NonGenericSubclass` is declared `final`, it can't be subclassed, so any class declaring a generic type can consider it non generic for all intents and purposes.  Good find!

Answer (score 16):

In Swift 2 it's possible to subclass a generic class:

```
class Something {}

class Base<T> {}

class Fancy : Base<Something> {}
```

Comment: Is there a preliminary documentation/blog quote on this to reference?

Comment: I didn't find it. I try it on playground.

Comment: You haven't subclassed the generic, you've subclassed the reified generic as a concrete type.  The object here would be `class Fancy : Base<T>`.  That's why @Tom van Zummeren's answer looks correct

Answer (score 15):

An alternative to the `typealias` [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24140324/143378) is to take the documentation literally:

> You can subclass a generic class, but the subclass must also be a
>   generic class.

So we make subclass a generic class, but of another type that we don't use for anything.

```
class foo<T> {

    func doSomething(t:T) -> T {
        return t;
    }
}

class bar<S> : foo<Int> {

    override func doSomething(t:Int) -> Int {
        return t * t;
    }
}

let b : bar = bar<AnyObject>()
b.doSomething(5) // 25 instead of 5
```

I prefer this approach to using `typealias` because it doesn't pollute the namespace with an additional type. This is of particular importance if the subclass (`bar`) is meant to be `public` or `internal`.

**Edit**

The documentation no longer includes the phrase about the limitation of generic subclasses. Hopefully this means that Apple plans to change this sooner than later.

Comment: Tested superficially with Beta 6.

Comment: it's funny how they design the language around the compiler limitations, instead of the viceversa..

Comment: This seems to work, but tidying it up with `typealias bar = bar<AnyObject>` won't

Comment: I suggest creating the intermediate with another name so that you can use the typealias with the technique above.\n  e.g.:  class GenericBase<T> {}\n
class _ExtendBase<T> : GenericBase<String> { }\n
typealias ExtendBase = _ExtendBase<AnyObject>

Answer (score 2):

This is now officially supported:

```
class Foo<RelatedType> {
    var object: RelatedType? = nil

    func myFunction(param: RelatedType) -> RelatedType? {
        return nil
    }
}

class Bar: Foo<String> {
    override func myFunction(param: String) -> String? {
        return self.object
    }
}
```