# Why generics don't compile?

Tags: generics, swift

I'm trying to implement following structure using generics. Getting a compiler error, can't figure out why.

```
class Translator<T:Hashable> {...}

class FooTranslator<String>:Translator<String> {...}
```

The idea is that Translator uses T as the type of a key in a dictionary. This can be e.g. a String or an enum. Subclass provides concrete dictionary.

But it fails because: "Type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'"

But String conforms to Hashable. It also doesn't work with Int, which also conforms to Hashable.

If I remove the type constraint, just for testing (where I also have to disable the dictionary, as I can't use anything not hashable as key there) - it compiles

```
class Translator<T> {...}

class FooTranslator<String>:Translator<String> {...}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not a Swift developer, but having seen similar problems in Java, I suspect the problem is that at the moment you're declaring a type parameter called `String` because you're declaring `class FooTranslator<String>` - so the type *argument* in `Translator<String>` is just that type parameter, which has no constraints. You don't *want* a type parameter at all, I suspect (i.e. you don't want your `FooTranslator` to be a generic class itself.)

As noted in comments, in Swift [subclasses of a generic class also have to be generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24138359/limitation-with-classes-derived-from-generic-classes-in-swift). You could possibly declare a throw-away type parameter, like this:

```
class FooTranslator<T>:Translator<String>
```

which still avoids declaring a new type parameter called `String`, which was what was causing the problem. It means you're introducing a new type parameter when you don't *want* any type parameters, but it's possibly better than nothing...

This is all on the assumption that you really need a subclass, e.g. to add or override members. On the other hand, if you just want a type which is *exactly* the same as `Translator<String>`, you should use a type alias instead:

```
typealias FooTranslator = Translator<String>
```

Or even mix the two in a horrible way, if you genuinely want a subclass but don't want to have to refer to it in a generic way:

```
class GenericFooTranslator<T>:Translator<String>
typealias FooTranslator = GenericFooTranslator<Int>
```

(Note that the `Int` here is deliberately not `String`, to show that the `T` in `Translator` isn't the same as the `T` in `FooTranslator`.)

Comment: That's not it. There's a Swift issue/limitation concerning this, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24138359/limitation-with-classes-derived-from-generic-classes-in-swift

Comment: @lxx: Ick. I suspect that's still the *cause*, but you want a different solution. I've edited my answer with a possible solution to try.

Comment: @Ixx: Right - it wasn't clear to me whether you might need a subclass for some other reason, where a type alias wouldn't be suitable. Will edit the answer further.

Answer (score 104):

For starters, let's explain the error:

Given:

```
class Foo<T:Hashable> { }

class SubFoo<String> : Foo<String> { }
```

The confusing part here is that we expect "String" to mean the Swift defined structure which holds a collection of characters.  But it's not.

Here, "String" is the name of the generic type we've given our new subclass, `SubFoo`.  This becomes very obvious if we make some changes:

```
class SubFoo<String> : Foo<T> { }
```

This line generates an error for `T` as the use of an undeclared type.

Then if we change the line to this:

```
class SubFoo<T> : Foo<T> { }
```

We're back to the same error you originally had, 'T' does not conform to 'Hashable'.  It's obvious here, because T isn't confusingly the name of an existing Swift type that happens to conform to 'Hashable'.  It's obvious 'T' is a generic.

When we write 'String', it's also just the placeholder name for a generic type, and not actually the `String` type that exists in Swift.

---

If we want a different name for a specific type of a generic class, the appropriate approach is almost certainly a `typealias`:

```
class Foo<T:Hashable> {

}

typealias StringFoo = Foo<String>
```

This is perfectly valid Swift, and it compiles just fine.

---

If instead what we want is to actually subclass and add methods or properties to a generic class, then what we need is a class or protocol that will make our generic more specific to what we need.

Going back to the original problem, let's first get rid of the error:

```
class Foo<T: Hashable>

class SubFoo<T: Hashable> : Foo<T> { }
```

This is perfectly valid Swift.  But it may not be particularly useful for what we're doing.

The only reason we can't do the following:

```
class SubFoo<T: String> : Foo<T> { }
```

is simply because `String` is not a Swift class--it's a structure.  And this isn't allowed for any structure.

---

If we write a new protocol that inherits from `Hashable`, we can use that:

```
protocol MyProtocol : Hashable { }

class Foo<T: Hashable> { }
class SubFoo<T: MyProtocol> : Foo<T> { }
```

This is perfectly valid.

Also, note that we don't actually have to inherit from `Hashable`:

```
protocol MyProtocol { }
class Foo<T: Hashable> { }
class SubFoo<T: Hashable, MyProtocol> { }
```

This is also perfectly valid.

However, note that, for whatever reason, Swift won't let you use a class here.  For example:

```
class MyClass : Hashable { }

class Foo<T: Hashable> { }
class SubFoo<T: MyClass> : Foo<T> { }
```

Swift mysteriously complains that 'T' does not conform to 'Hashable' (even when we add the necessary code to make it so.

---

In the end, the right approach, and the most Swift-appropriate approach is going to be writing a new protocol that inherits from 'Hashable' and adds whatever functionality to it you need.

It shouldn't be strictly important that our subclass accept a `String`.  It should be important that whatever our subclass takes, it has the necessary methods and properties that we need for whatever we're doing.