# Define a variable that conforms to more than one protocol/protocol+superclass

Tags: generics, swift

I'm trying to implement a not trivial (at least for my level) relationship between types.

Class A and B are subclasses of a class MySuperClass, and I'm letting them implement a protocol "MyProtocol"

```
class MySuperclass {...}

protocol MyProtocol {
     func myProtocolMethod() 
}

class A:MySuperclass, MyProtocol {...}

class B:MySuperclass, MyProtocol {...}
```

My class "Container" has a variable x, which can be either an instance of A or B

```
class Container {... var x:???? ....}
```

As maybe imaginable from the ???? my problem is that I would like that I can use x as both as MyProtocol and MySuperclass.

Just today I solved a very similar problem in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27962413/how-to-declare-variable-that-extends-specific-superclass-and-conforms-to-a-proto) and I thought I could apply that here but I'm not succeeding.

The idea would be to declare the type of the variable such that it satisfies a constraint `<T where T:MySuperclass, T:MyProtocol>`, but where do I put that? Everything I have tried so far didn't really make sense and failed.

I tried, for example:

```
class Container<T where T:MySuperclass, T:MyProtocol>

class Container {... var x:T ...}
```

but I instantiate and assign T in `Container`, and when I do this I get a compiler error:

```
class Container {... self.x = A() ....}
```

"Type A is not convertible to 'T'"

But actually it should, because A satisfies the type constraints.

Edit: Thanks to [arshajii's anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27973034/930450) I understood why this is not possible. But I still need to know how to solve my initial problem.

I don't know if generics is actually the correct approach for this. I think I don't really need a type variable, what I need is rather something like an aggregate type...

Edit 2- I know I can implement this by just implementing a subclass. Was just wondering if there are other approaches. But thinking again a subclass seems to be the best way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

`T` could be another type (e.g. `FooImpl2`) completely unrelated to `FooImpl`:

```
           Foo
          /   \
    FooImpl   FooImpl2
```

A `Foo` instance cannot be assigned to a (potential) variable of type `FooImpl2`, hence the error.

Comment: Thanks! (+1) now I get that part. But I still don't know how to solve my original problem :/ Maybe I should remove the Java tag as the solution of that one needs Swift expertise.

Answer (score 0):

This is just one of strategies to workaround this kind of problems.

- Declare a protocol of `MySuperClass`
- use ["Protocol Composition"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID282)

```
// declare Protocol of MySuperClass type
protocol MySuperClassType {
    func mySuperClassMethod()
}

// Make the superclass conforms to it.
class MySuperclass: MySuperClassType {
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    func mySuperClassMethod() {}
}

protocol MyProtocol {
    func myProtocolMethod()
}

class A: MySuperclass, MyProtocol {
    func myProtocolMethod() { }
}

class B: MySuperclass, MyProtocol {
    func myProtocolMethod() { }
}

class Container {

    // use "Protocol Composition" to declare the property.
    var x: protocol<MySuperClassType, MyProtocol>

    // ...
}
```

Comment: The problem with this, in my particular case, is that I want the variable to be usable by existing apis as an instance of MySuperClass. An example: If MySuperClass is an UIView, even if I create an extension to make x conform to a protocol "MySuperClassType" with UIView methods, I can't do view.addSubview(x).

Comment: Then you should take another strategy, something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474061/whats-the-swift-equivalent-of-declaring-typedef-someclasssomeprotocol-mytype/26475054#26475054

Answer (score 0):

```
class Container {... var x: protocol<MySuperclassProtocol, MyProtocol> ....}
```

Ensure that  `MySuperclass` conforms to `MySuperclassProtocol`

Comment: The problem with this, in my particular case, is that I want the variable to be usable by existing apis as an instance of MySuperClass. An example: If MySuperClass is an UIView, even if I create an extension to make x conform to a protocol "MySuperClassType" with UIView methods, I can't do view.addSubview(x).

Comment: `view.addSubview(unsafeBitCast(x, UIView.self))`

Comment: I assumed that you were not aware of `unsafeBitCast`. I've tried to tackle this problem myself, but haven't found a concrete solution yet.

Comment: Swift protocols do not support subclass dependencies as of yet.