# Which one is better option for maintaining application or activities?

Tags: android

**Which one is better option for application or activities?**

**A.** **BaseActivity class**, [OR]

**B.Singleton class.**

In my application most of activities do same actions like show toasts, maintaining sessions, static variables,show EditText errors, HTTP request/response, etc., For now I'm extends BaseActivity in all my Activities where needed.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right path, a `BaseClass` is preferred because most of those thing you mentioned (Manipulating `Toasts`, `EditText` functions) require a `Context` to work with. A Singleton class would need that `Context` passed to it with every method call - a BaseClass does not (since it is technically a `Context` itself).

Answer (score 0):

These are two fundermental different design patterns.

1. BaseActivity --> Inheritance
2. Use a Singleton in all activities --> Aggregate pattern

You find many posts in the [internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269496/inheritance-vs-aggregation) about advantage and disadvantage of both patterns.

For your specific problem I would suggest to use inheritance. It is a common way to do and you should [avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons) to use the singleton pattern if possible.