# What is the opposite part of Inheritance?

Tags: oop, inheritance, language-agnostic, aggregation

I am learning OOP from scratch. I have some confusion about Inheritance and Aggregation. After researching on the net I am more confused that is Inheritance opposite of Aggregation ? Is it true ?

Comment: That's a little like saying that "green" is the opposite of "three". They serve two different purposes.

Comment: Maybe you're thinking about [*aggregation* versus *composition*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/61376/aggregation-vs-composition)?

Comment: The word "opposite" is not well-defined when used with respect to software development patterns.

Inheritance and aggregation are two different tools to solve the same problem (roughly *"how can I extend the functionality of a class"*). A comparison can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/269496/87698. I am voting to close this as a duplicate, feel free to edit and clarify your question if you disagree.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inheritance vs. Aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269496/inheritance-vs-aggregation)

Answer (score 0):

> Inheritance is a specialised form of Aggregation. For example

Handsfree is aggregated in cell phone. (Aggregation)
Motherboard is composed of ICs. (Composition)
A policeman is a human. (Inheritance)

These are types of association from weak to strong

> Association->Aggregation->Composition->Inheritance.