# Inherit class without parent type in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, types

How can I inherit from another class without adopting the parent type?

For example I want to be able to let `Car` adopt all methods and properties of `Vehicle` without being recognized as an Object of type `Vehicle`.

Is there a convenient way of doing this in Java without duplicating all methods and properties?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand the question but you might want to define the `interface Vehicle` and let `Car` implement that interface.

Comment: So, you want delegation instead of inheritance. Java does not have a convenient way to implement delegation.

Comment: you can extract the methods of vehicle to an interface that will be used by vehicle and by car. Then your car does not have to be a vehicle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on your definition of convenient. You are a looking for  [Forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forwarding_(object-oriented_programming))/Composition/Aggregation, essentially:

```
class B {
  A a;
  T foo() { return a.foo(); }
}
```

Which implies that all methods defined in `A` need to be duplicated in `B`.

This often comes up in discussion about [Inheritance vs. Aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269496/inheritance-vs-aggregation).

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want to do is use the delegate pattern there is no easy way to do this with native Java, you could use the [project Lombok Delegate](https://projectlombok.org/features/Delegate.html) to make it really convenient.

Answer (score 2):

If Car and Vehicle inherit from a common patent, they will have the same methods without Car being a Vehicle and no duplication.

Answer (score 0):

it's very hard you have to use bytecode reverse endangering library like javassist.
here some example of using javassist to manipulate java class file

http://www.javassist.org/tutorial/tutorial2.html#intro

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Framework, you can define abstract bean for that purpose https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-child-bean-definitions