# In Lucene how can a TokenFilter emit more than one term?

Tags: java, lucene, tokenize

I'm working with Lucene 3.2. How can I use a TokenFilter that doesn't just filter/modify a term, but can also insert other terms into the stream?

For example, I want a filter that take as input "tv42lcd" and insert into the stream the words "tv42lcd",  "tv", "42", "lcd".

I'm aware that I could do this by implementing my own Tokenizer. But I rather still use the provided StandardTokenizer.

Comment: How would your tokenizer know where to split the terms?  e.g. why not "tv42lcd", "tv", "42", "lc", "d" or "tv4", "2l", "cd"?

Comment: This is just an example. But in my application I split based on the numeric chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always mix default with custom: use `StandardTokenizer` logic where possible, then wrap its output and add custom tokenization on the top. You can achieve this by extending, but it's [almost always better to use composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399544/difference-between-inheritance-and-composition).