# How do you extend datetime.date in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need a class extending `datetime.date` adding logic that is relevant to my application. It used to work well with Python 2, but I don't understand how to write the constructor in Python 3. I thought the standard way to write a derived constructor in Python 3 was like this:

```
from datetime import date

class my_date(date):
    def __init__(self, year, month, day):
        super().__init__(year, month, day)

date(2020, 4, 18)
my_date(2020, 4, 18)
```

However, this code fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    my_date(2020, 4, 18)
  File "/tmp/test.py", line 5, in __init__
    super().__init__(year, month, day)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

What should I do to properly call the super constructor?

In particular, `datetime.date` clearly accepts to be initialized with three numbers. Why does the error message say it takes one argument? And why is the problem in `object.__init__()` instead of in `datetime.date.__init__()`?

Comment: Looking at the Python source of [`datetime.date`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c606624af8d4cb3b4a052fb263bb983b3f87585b/Lib/datetime.py#L793) you’ll notice that it doesn’t have an `__init__()` method, only a `__new__()` constructor. That would explain the above error. Also note that `year`, `month`, `day` are decorated (i.e. read only) properties, not instance values.

Comment: Replace `super().__init__(year, month, day)` with `pass`.

Comment: That `__init__` was pointless even in Python 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer from the comments:

[Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/356307/jens)

> Looking at the Python source of [datetime.date](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c606624af8d4cb3b4a052fb263bb983b3f87585b/Lib/datetime.py#L793) you’ll notice that it doesn’t have an `__init__()` method, only a `__new__()` constructor. That would explain the above error. Also note that `year`, `month`, `day` are decorated (i.e. read only) properties, not instance values.

[accdias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6789321/accdias)

> Replace `super().__init__(year, month, day)` with `pass`

```
from datetime import date

class my_date(date):
        pass

d1 = date(2020, 4, 18)
d2 = my_date(2020, 4, 18)

print(d1,d2)
```

Outputs:

```
2020-04-18 2020-04-18
```

You might think about using composition instead of inheritance for whatever you need done:

```
class MyDateClass:
    def __init__(self, a_date):
        self.my_date = a_date

    # add members/methods that do stuff wiht a_date
```

instead of inheriting date.

See

- [Inheritance vs. Aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269496/inheritance-vs-aggregation)
- [What is the difference between inheritance and composition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502167/what-is-the-difference-between-inheritance-and-composition)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to extend date then you can do something like this.

```
from datetime import date


class MyDate(date):
    def __init__(self, year, month, day):
       print(self)


print(date(2020, 4, 18))
print(MyDate(2020, 4, 20))
```

Comment: It is a convention to call the `super` constructor when inhereting

Comment: @Tomerikoo yes, I completely agree. But in this use case rather than extending date class using date class object makes more sense.