# What are the main differences between composition and inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance, composition

Please can a more experienced member give me brief explanation about the very basic aspects of composition vs inheritance?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399544/difference-between-inheritance-and-composition

Comment: Also see - http://www.javaworld.com/jw-11-1998/jw-11-techniques.html