# Add custom text on image in jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe

How  to create java program in netbeans  that make  the user select an image by pressing  button and select the image ,   and after that make the user add text by pressing  button and typing on that image.

....... I want to create 2 buttons  one for select images and one for add Text on that image.......

Can anyone help me please.  And thanks

Comment: I want the user add text on that image by button

Comment: `and after that make the user add text by pressing button and typing on that image.` - please define your requirement better. Where is the text displayed?. Is the text centered on the label? Can you add text in more than one place? A typical way to do this might be to add a JTextField to the label when you click on the button. Then you type in the text field and when you hit enter you save the text from the text field as the text of the label.

Comment: I want the user to add the Text anywhere he want on the image that shows in the label that  he is selected before.  By clicking on button named example(ADD TEXT)

Comment: 1) Still didn't answer if you can have text in multiple places. 2) How does clicking on the button help? How do you know where to place the text?

Comment: 1)  No...   2) because that is my homework make a button to add text ......     3) let's say the text will be in the bottom on image

Comment: I created jlabel and 2 buttons under the label one for select images and one to add the Text  on that image..  My problem is i cant add the Text  on the image

Answer (score 0):

> after that make the user add text by pressing button and typing on that image.

So when you click on the button I would suggest that you:

1. Display a `JOptionPane` to prompt for the text to be displayed.
2. Then you get the text from the option pane and add the text to the label. How you add the text depends on your exact requirement on how the text should be displayed. Check out: [Clear previously drawn string over an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20534068/clear-previously-drawn-string-over-an-image/20534152#20534152) for 4 possible ways to do this.