# C++ inheritance and overloading, calling a base method once overloaded

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

Currently I have a class which contains another and provides a wrapper for some of its methods and provides others intact:

```
class bar {
public:

    int calculate1(int a, int b) {
        return f.calculate1(a, b);
    }

    int calculate2(int a, int b) {
        a ++;
        b ++;
        return f.calculate2(a, b);
    }

private:
    foo f
}
```

Where `foo` is a class containing 2 methods `calculate1` and `calculate2`, both taking 2 `int`s and returning an `int`.

Is there a better way to achieve this with inheritance? It would be nice to be able to get rid of this:

```
    int calculate1(int a, int b) {
        return f.calculate1(a, b);
    }
```

But this would need to call the very function it is overloading, and I'm not sure how to do that:

```
    int calculate2(int a, int b) {
        a ++;
        b ++;
        return f.calculate2(a, b);
    }
```

Is it even possible or advisable? Is there another method to be used in this situation?

apologies if some of my code is a bit dodgy, as you can tell I'm a bit new to C++, but I hope I got the message across.

Comment: Where is the inheritance here? This is composition.

Comment: I'm asking how a similar effect would be achived using inheritance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`1.`Is there a better way to achieve this with inheritance?`

Of course!

```
//sg
#include<iostream>
class foo {
public:
    int calculate1(int a, int b) {
        return a * b;
    }

    int calculate2(int a, int b) {
        a ++;
        b ++;
        return a + b;
    }

};
class bar: public foo {
public:

    int calculate1(int a, int b) {
        return foo::calculate1(a, b);
    }

    int calculate2(int a, int b) {
        a++;
        b++;
        return foo::calculate2(a, b);
    }
};
using namespace std;
int main() {
    bar b;
    cout << b.calculate2(1,2) << endl;
    cout << b.calculate1(1,2) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**To inherit or compose? (is inheritance really better here?)**

`2. Is it even possible or advisable?`

We have seen that it is possible. As to whether it is advisable or not, semantics of foo and bar <sup>*</sup>will decide that. **As they stand**, I think inheritance looks *much* better, foo contains the basic calculators, bar needs to use them besides doing something extra. Of course, this is what I *think* happens and how you intend things to be, may/not be correct. ?In which case composition may win.

As a thumb rule, you can try saying the following two lines out loud :

a) bar *is a* foo (as in Car is a Vehicle)

b) bar *has a* foo (as in Car has an Engine)

If **a** makes more sense, inherit, otherwise compose. If none of them makes any sense, then you should probably give your design another cup of coffee.

Find more reasons [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399544/difference-between-inheritance-and-composition)

---

*

Think of `foo` as a class `widget` and `bar` as a specialized widget, say `textbox`. Let `calculate` be a `renderer` (a function that draws textbox on screen), you do special things to arguments in `bar` and then call the standard renderer in `foo`. In this case, it makes sense to say that `bar` *is a* `foo`. On the other hand, let `bar` be a constraint solver which takes the arguments, does some calculation and passes them on to a standard la engine `foo` to do final calculations, then I'd say that `bar` *has a* linear algebra engine, `foo`.

Comment: Could you explain why you think inheritance looks better? I would argue that composition looks much better here. Also, your *is-a* *has-a* thing is confusing, because you are using inheritance to implement a *has-a* relationship.

Comment: You changed the inheritance to `public`. That makes the answer self-consistent, but there is nothing in OP's code to suggest that inheritance is better than composition here. You are basing your judgement on imagined classes.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes. It was unintentional in the first place. 
Ran out of words there. I did mention that semantics of `foo` and `bar` should decide inheritance vs composition.

Answer (score 3):

To call a base class method, use qualification:

```
return foo::calculate1(a, b);
```

Remember to ensure that your base class methods are `virtual` if you want them to be called polymorphically.

Comment: thanks, do you think this is preferable to composition?

Comment: @jayjay in this case, it may be; if you're unsure about the decision, I'd recommend reading http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/134097/why-should-i-prefer-composition-over-inheritance

Answer (score 2):

It possible via this way:

```
class bar : public foo {
public:

    int calculate2(int a, int b) {        
        return foo::calculate2(a+1, b+1);
    }
};
```