# Is Scanner(System.in) considered an example of composition

Tags: java

I am just now learning about composition. Would Scanner(System.in) be considered an example of composition?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399544/difference-between-inheritance-and-composition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is.

The point is that `Scanner` **has a** "something" that it can read data from, and it knows how to process that data into tokens.

That "something" can be standard input, a file, a string etc; but there isn't a separate subclass for reading from each of these these things. Indeed, you can't extend `Scanner`, as it is `final`.

What you might find interesting about `new Scanner(System.in)` is that the `Scanner` doesn't keep hold of `System.in` directly: if you look at the [constructor's source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/util/Scanner.java#607), you will see:

```
public Scanner(InputStream source) {
  this(new InputStreamReader(source),    
      WHITESPACE_PATTERN);
}

private Scanner(Readable source, Pattern pattern) {
  // ...
  this.source = source;
   // ...
}
```

`source` (e.g. `System.in`) is wrapped in an `InputStreamReader`, and it is *that* which is held onto by the `Scanner`. So you've got two levels of composition:

- `Scanner` has a `Readable` (the `InputStreamReader`);
- The `InputStreamReader` has an `InputStream` (e.g. `System.in`).