# What if I create an object of Class Two in Class One itself and then access Class Two's data...What will be the difference?

Tags: java

Here in this code snippet of Object Relation, I am taking reference of Class Two in Class One, and through it I am accessing class Two's members.

What if I create Class Two's Object in Class One itself and then access its methods? What will be the difference in doing it ?

I know I am missing some concept here but I am not getting it.

```
// Object Relation Using References

 package Object_Relation;
 class One {
    // Instance Variables
    int x;
    Two t;
    public One(Two t) {
        this.t = t;
        x=10;
    }

    void display() {
        System.out.println("Class One Members : ");
        System.out.println("x = "+x);
        System.out.println("Displaying Class Two Members using its Method");
        t.display();
   System.out.println("Displaying Class Two Members using its reference :");
        System.out.println("y = "+t.y);
    }
}

class Two {

    //  Instance Variables
    int y;
    public Two(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("y = "+y);
    }

}

public class UsingReference {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Two t2 = new Two(20);
        One o = new One(t2);
        o.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a real question?  What are you asking?

Comment: See if the following helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399544/difference-between-inheritance-and-composition

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen My Query is that i am able get the same output from both the ways, I am confused in both the approaches.

Comment: The difference is that you have two pointers to follow instead of just one. The memory location of One and Two have no relationship and could be anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly the question is?

But here in the example One and Two both are different classes. And in-order to access the non-static member variables you need a object of class Two.

Are you looking for some concept about inner class in java:-
Example

```
public class OuterClass {

  int i;

  public void method1() {
    System.out.println("Inside Method 1");
  }

  class InnerClass {
    int j;

    public void method2() {
      System.out.println("Inside Method 2");
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // To instantiate an inner class, you must first instantiate the outer class
    OuterClass outerObject = new OuterClass();
    outerObject.method1();

    // Then, create the inner object within the outer object
    OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();
    innerObject.method2();
  }

}
```

PS: Here InnerClass is a member of OuterClass.

Comment: I am able get the same output from both the ways, I am confused in both the approaches.

Comment: I think then you are looking for dependency injection concept.