# How do I extend abstract class in Activity?

Tags: android, abstract-class

I have an abstract class named `Customer` and have an `MainActivity` extends `Activity`, but how do I extend that Customer abstract class in MainActivity?

Comment: Java doesn't support multiple inheritance, Use composition instead...

Comment: `Customer extends Activity` and `your_class extends Customer`. or something like the same scenario.

Comment: By using composition we can able to extend more than one class in java.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Inheritance and Composition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399544/difference-between-inheritance-and-composition)

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you *cannot* multiple inherit. Instead of it, you could write:

```
public class Customer extends Activity{
  ...
}
```

```
public class class_name extends Customer{
  ...
}
```

---

You could use composition. A code which used composition:

```
public class class_name{
  private Customer var_name;
  ...
}
```

For more information: [Difference between Inheritance and Composition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2399544/6366398)