# class name variable in same class not understand concept

Tags: java, class

I could not understand the following concept of how it works when we create the class object

```
class MyClass {
    int data;
    MyClass var;  
}
```

I'm totally confused about how it will work and what is the purpose of creating the object of the same class name. I can't understand what is the concept of this declaration.

Comment: Are you familiar with a linked list?  The concept is practically identical.

Comment: In real life: you are a Person. And you have a father. Your father is also a Person. Replace MyClass with Person in your example, and var with father, and you have this real-life situation modeled as a class.

Comment: yes but how it work as i mentioned method name with same as class name called constructor but what this type of declaration called ???

Comment: You have no method in the code you posted, and no constructor either. So I'm not sure what you're talking about. What you have is a class, with two fields (or instance variables). https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html

Comment: Chicken-and-egg dilemma, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a completely valid Java class declaration. An example of what `MyClass var;` means in your code is this one:

Imagine this class is called `Directory` (it represents a directory location in a hard drive in real life) and we want to simulate that a directory can have more (sub) directories (for simplicity, only one :) ). So we could simulate this using this structure:

```
class Directory {
    int amountOfFolders;
    Directory subdiretory;         // <-- child object(directory)!
    // Directory[] subdiretories;  // out of curiosity, this would be much more real
}
```

This way when we create a `Directory` object and set its child directory(ies) and do some stuff with it.

This is called *Composition* (read more at [Difference between Inheritance and Composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399544/difference-between-inheritance-and-composition) and [Inheritance and Composition](https://www.baeldung.com/java-inheritance-composition) (the "Composition’s Basics" part) )

See below code commented for some more details...

```
class MyClass {

    int data;
    // attribute of type MyClass, this can represent a hierarchical structure
    // in real life applications.
    MyClass var;

   // this is not a class method, but its constructor, used to create instances
   // of this class, i.e.: MyClass c = new MyClass();
   public MyClass() {
   }

   // this is another constructor, which receives a parameter for setting its
   // attribute data, i.e.: MyClass c = new MyClass(3);
   public MyClass(int data) {
       this.data = data;
   }
}
```

**Demo**: https://ideone.com/2qirCQ

Here is the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/composition-demo/blob/master/README.md) with this code.

Comment: thanks i can understand but please can you show me its implementation..with simple example ..

Answer (score 2):

When you want to model some real world scenarios, you might have to use this notion.

For example, think of a Tree's branch. A tree's branch might have n number of branches on it. A branch will have reference to the branches next to it.

```
class Branch {
    Branch branch1;
    Branch branch2;
    Branch branch3;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, each instance of `MyClass` can have a reference to another instance of `MyClass`. The name doesn't give much of a hint as to why you would want it. But in general this kind of structure allows linking, decorating and nesting.

For example, you could implement a chain of processing steps. Each one calls the next one in the chain until the end (`var == null`).

Alternatively, your class could "wrap" another instance of the class and do something like log method calls before delegating them to the wrapped instance.

A similar structure can be used for modeling trees as a `Node` that each has a list of child nodes (`List<Node> children`). The leaf nodes would have no children.