# When to create an Instance vs Inheritance

Tags: c#

Please consider the below:

```
public class A 
{
  public string MethodA()
  {
    return "Hello from Class A";
  }  
}

public class B 
{  
   public void MethodB()
   {
     ClassA classAObj = new ClassA();
     Console.WriteLine(classAObj.MethodA());
   }
}

public class C : A
{
   public void MethodC()
   {
       Console.WriteLine(MethodA());
   }
}
```

My question here is, under what circumstance do I create an instance of Class A (as shown in `Class B`) or inherit the members of the parent class (`Class A`) as shown in `Class C`.

I know OOP concepts say use inheritence whenever you want to share the behavior of the members of a parent class in the child class. In this case I'm not changing nor overriding the base class' default definition.

Should I create an object reference to class A or simply inherit Class A?

Comment: This example is too contrived (and not valid code) to give an answer - it always depends on the specific circumstances whether to use inheritance or composition (this is what class `B` is doing), see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399544/difference-between-inheritance-and-composition

Comment: Your classes `B` and `C` is invalid. You cannot call methods directly is class like that. Did you mean to put Console.WriteLine` inside another method?

Comment: @BuildItBusk Correct. That was an error

Comment: You should generally [favour composition over inheritence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance). As inheritance is generally less flexible. There is even an argument that states that inheritance is a contrived concept that only works in an academic sense and should [just be abandoned.](https://codeburst.io/inheritance-is-evil-stop-using-it-6c4f1caf5117)

Comment: I'm prone to agree @Liam

Comment: Both patterns are okay in different situations. Inheritance is an "is" relationship... a *dog* is an *animal*. Composition is a *has* or *can* relationship. A *dog* can *bark* and a dog *has four legs*. Practically speaking, it is usually better to prefer composition over inheritance because a class can be composed of several classes while it can only inherit one.

Comment: You should read design pattern , will you get good exposure how and when use inheritance or object..

Comment: This is the problem with this question I'm afraid, ultimately this is opinion based

Comment: Yeah this is for my thesis at school. They don't mind us using either approach, as long as your justifications can make sense

Comment: @JohnWu Please post that as your answer

Comment: Here is an overview of the ["Gang of four" patterns in C#](https://www.dofactory.com/net/design-patterns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both patterns are okay in different situations. Inheritance is an "is" relationship... a dog *is* an animal. Composition is a *has* or *can* relationship. A dog *can* bark and a dog *has* four legs.

Practically speaking, it is usually better to prefer composition over inheritance because a class can be composed of several classes while it can only inherit one.