# Abstract object in constructor java

Tags: java, abstract-class

For a computer science project I have a Movie class that implements Comparable with Comedy, Action, and MovieTrilogy extending it. The problem I am having is that MovieTrilogy takes 3 Movie objects in the constructor. The MovieTrilogy class needs to have the Movie objects as instance variables which means I need to declare an abstract object. I belive what my teacher would want is to declare the MovieTrilogy object with Comedy and Action objects, but I would still need to store them as instance variables. How would I do this? The movie constructor as well as the MovieTrilogy class are atatched below.

```
public class MovieTrilogy extends Movie{
   private Movie movie1;
   private Movie movie3;
   private Movie movie2;
   public MovieTrilogy(Movie Movie1, Movie Movie2, Movie Movie3){
      movie1 = Movie1;
      movie2 = Movie2;
      movie3 = Movie3;
   }
```

And this is the movie class.

```
public abstract class Movie implements Comparable<Movie>{
   private int Score;
   private String Title;
   public Movie(String title, int score){
      Title = title;
      Score = score;
   }
   public int getScore(){ return Score; }
   public String getTitle(){ return Title; }
   public int compareTo(Movie movie){
      return this.compareTo(movie);
   }
   public String getGenre(){
      return null;
   }
   public String toString(){
      return Title + " with a score of "  + Score;
   }
}
```

The code below is the error it gives me trying to compile `MovieTrilogy`.

```
MovieTrilogy.java:5: error: constructor Movie in class Movie cannot be applied to given types;
public MovieTrilogy(Movie Movie1, Movie Movie2, Movie Movie3){
                                                            ^
required: String,int
found:    no arguments
```

Comment: If the constructor is asking for the abstract base class, you can still pass it an instance of a subclass. E.g. if `ActionMovie extends Movie`, then `new MovieTriology(new ActionMovie(), ...)` is valid.

Comment: `Movie#compareTo(Movie movie)` is looking a little infinite.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am however getting an error when I try to do that because I cant declare the movie instance variables. The error is in the edit

Comment: `MovieTrilogy` should not inherit from `Movie`, `MovieTrilogy` should be composed of three `Movie` instances. See [Difference between Inheritance and Composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399544/difference-between-inheritance-and-composition).

Comment: My teacher said that MovieTrilogy should be "a concrete class called MovieTrilogy which extends Movie. The class should have a constructor that takes three Movie objects as parameters." That's pasted directly from the assignment,

Comment: @BCurbs It'll still be to your benefit to understand why this is a potentially questionable design decision. There are valid reasons why it might make sense to do it this way, but not many. Consider this: a trilogy doesn't have a director, a movie does. (It also makes little sense to specialize on "trilogy", but that's a separate issue :)

Comment: @BCurbs Can you add the original homework document to your question so we can see the exact wording and the whole context of the assignment?

Answer (score 4):

Okay so first let me address your specific error. In order for `MovieTrilogy` to extend `Movie` it has to satisfy the constructor that *you enforced* in the `Movie` class. So in order to construct a `Movie` (and consequently a `MovieTrilogy`) you have to provide a `title` and a `score` via a super method in the constructor.

So something like this:

```
public MovieTrilogy(Movie Movie1, Movie Movie2, Movie Movie3) {

    super("Trilogy title", 0);

    movie1 = Movie1;
    movie2 = Movie2;
    movie3 = Movie3;
}
```

---

However I wonder whether it is a good idea for `MovieTrilogy` to extend a `Movie`, as a trilogy doesn't really represent a specific movie, so can't be expected to have the same properties a movie does. I would recommend researching into inheritance as a programming concept to get some more clarity on how you should be thinking about it.

From the fact your constructor takes `title` and `score` it seems like you might be trying to represent some form of media that is rated so maybe you could have a structure like this:

```
class RatedTitle(String title, int score);
class Movie(String title, int score) extends RatedTitle(title, score);
class MovieTrilogy(String title, int score, Movie[] movies) extends RatedTitle(title, score);
```

(I hope you can think of a much better name than `RatedTitle`)

---

**Edit**

As @JohnHenly pointed out and said so eloquently,

> `Movie#compareTo(Movie movie)` is looking a little infinite.

You seem to have a misunderstanding of implementing the `Comparable` interface and at the moment using the comparison method will result in a `StackOverflowException`. By returning `this.compareTo(movie)` you are trying to call the `compareTo` method defined in `Movie` which will then attempt to return `this.compareTo(movie)` again and again until the JVM can't take it anymore.

There are many articles that explain how to override `toCompare` properly but you might want to read this one because of the amazing title: [Add the Comparable flavor, and taste the feeling.](https://medium.com/omarelgabrys-blog/comparing-objects-307400115f88)

Comment: Thank you. I believe this is the answer.

Comment: I would even add the title as an argument to the `MovieTrilogy` constructor

Comment: I think that most modern IDEs will warn you about a method recursing infinitely.