# How to model (sub)classes with identical attributes and methods?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, oom

I am trying to model the following situation in Java, but I suppose it might be a general OOP problem:
I have 3 (or maybe more) different classes, which have some attributes and methods in common, and some attributes and methods which are specific to each of the classes.

So far, this is a classical inheritance situation.

The problem: The third class contains some attributes/methods identical to (only) the first class and some identical to (only) the second class. Polymorphism should also be used.

To be more specific: I want to model stations where people can borrow things: There are `BikeStations`, `CanoeStations` and `BikeAndCanoeStations`, with one or more common behavior method(s) (for polymorphism).

As - at the first look - this seems to be a classical inheritance problem, one could model the classes as follows:

```
// Superclass (Station)
public abstract class Station {

   // common attributes

   // common methods

   public abstract void doSomething();
}
```

```
// Subclass 1 (BikeStation)
public class BikeStation extends Station {

   private int someBikeSpecificAttribute;

   // more bike station specific attributes

   public void doSomething() {
      // bike station specific stuff
   }

   // more bike station specific methods
}
```

```
// Subclass 2 (CanoeStation)
public class CanoeStation extends Station {

   private int someCanoeSpecificAttribute;

   // more canoe station specific attributes

   public void doSomething() {
      // canoe station specific stuff
   }

   // more canoe station specific methods
}
```

```
// Subclass 3 (BikeAndCanoeStation)
public class BikeAndCanoeStation extends Station {

   private int someBikeSpecificAttribute;   // same as in BikeStation
   private int someCanoeSpecificAttribute;  // same as in CanoeStation

   // more mixed station specific attributes

   public void doSomething() { 
      // bike station specific stuff (same as in BikeStation)
      // canoe station specific stuff (same as in CanoeStation)
   }

   // more mixed station specific methods
}
```

However, it doesn't feel right to just copy the attributes and methods/statements from the first two classes to the third. This just does not feel like good OOP.
It produces redundant code and I cannot easily add other classes (stations) later.

So I thought about using Interfaces or even the [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), but this only solves the behavioral problem (i.e. the methods), if at all.

How would you model such a situation with good OOP (preferably in Java)?

*(edited question to include/clarify the use of polymorphism.)*

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are looking for composition. [Difference between Inheritance and Composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399544/difference-between-inheritance-and-composition) is good read.

Basically `BikeAndCanoeStation` will depend on `BikeStation` and `CanoeStation` and delegate the specific operation to them.

```
public class BikeAndCanoeStation extends Station {

  private BikeStation bikeStation;
  private CanoeStation canoeStation;

  // more mixed station specific attributes

  public void doSomethingBikeSpecific() {
     this.bikeStation.doSomethingBikeSpecific();
  }

  public void doSomethingCanoeSpecific() {
    this.canoeStation.doSomethingCanoeSpecific();
  }

  // more mixed station specific methods
}
```

I would still extract the methods in interfaces to be more clear what each implementor is supposed to do.