# Showing information from a class attached to another class info

Tags: java

Imagine I have a class Establishments, a class Hospitals that extends from Establishments and a class Poles. Now hospitals have several poles, and when I display my hospitals, I want to show the poles that are attached to that hospital, but how can I access those, if hospitals don't extend from Poles? Is this even possible?

```
public class Pole{
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private int nTelephone;
    private String hospital;
    public Pole(){
        name = "";
        address = "";
        nPhone = 0;
        hospital = "";
    }
    public Pole(String name, int nTelephone, String address, String hospital){
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.nPhone = nPhone;
        this.hospital = hospital;
    }
    public void setPole(String name, int nTelephone, String address, String hospital){
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.nPhone = nPhone;
        this.hospital = hospital;
    }
    public void getPole(){
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Address: " + address);
        System.out.println("Phone number: " + nPhone);
        System.out.println("Belongs to hospital " + hospital);
    }
}

public class Hospital extends Establishment{
    private String address;
    public Hospital(){
        address = "";
    }
    public Hospital (String name, String address, String email){
        super(name, email);
        this.address = address;
    }
    public void setHospital(String name, String address, String email){
        setHospital(name, email);
        this.address = address;
    }
    public void getHospital(){
        getEstablishment();
        System.out.println("Address:"+ this.address);

    }
    public String getHospitalName(){
       return getEstablishmentName();
    }
}

public class Establishment{
    private String name;
    private String email;
    public Establishment(){
        name = "";
        email = "";
    }
    public Establishment (String name, String email){
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }
    public void getEstablishment(){
        /*When called shows the name and email of an establishment
         *
         * */
        System.out.println("Name: " + this.name);
        System.out.println("Email: " + this.email);
    }
    public void setEstabelecimento(String name, String email){
        /*When called creates an establishment
         *
         * */
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getEstablishmentName(){
        return this.name;
    }
}

    public void addHospital() {
        Scanner r = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name;
        String email;
        String address;
        String namePole;
        String addressPole;
        int nTelPole;
        int addPole;
        System.out.println("==== Add Hospital ====");
        System.out.println("Enter name");
        name = r.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter email");
        email = r.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter address");
        address = r.nextLine();
        numberHospitals++;
        unidadesHospitalares[numHospitals - 1] = new Hospital();
        unidadesHospitalares[numHospitals - 1].setHospital(name, email, address);
        System.out.println("==== Add Pole====");
        System.out.println("Enter name");
        namePole = r.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter phone number");
        nTelPole = r.nextInt();
        r.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the address");
        addressPole = r.nextLine();
        r.nextLine(); //When used after a nextInt, it serves to clear the input buffer, and prevent the nextLine field from being misunderstood by the program
        numPoles ++;
        poles[numPoles - 1] = new Pole();
        String associatedHospital = hospitalUnits[numeroHospitais - 1].getNameHospital();
        poles[numPoles - 1].setPole(namePole, nTelPole, addressPole, associatedHospital);
        sleep(3000);
        clear();
```

These are the 3 classes I was talking about, and this is where I try to Implement the addition of hospitals and poles. Then I have the showHospital, which right now only shows hospitals info, but I also want it to show the info from poles. Right now looks like this:

```
public void showHospital(){
    if (numberHospitals == 0){
        System.out.println("There are no Hospitals!");
    }
    System.out.println("==== Hospitals ====");
    for (int i =0 ; i< numeroHospitals ; i++){
        unitsHospitals[i].getHospital();
        System.out.println("====");
    }
    sleep(3000);
    clear();
    menuHospital();
}
```

Comment: Don't confuse composition with inheritance, which is what you seem to be doing. The Hospital class satisfies the "is-a" relationship rule with Establishment, and so the former can extend from the latter, but no such relationship exists between hospitals and poles. Instead, the relationship is a "has-a" or "has-several" relationship where a hospital can have one or many poles. That is solved not by inheritance but by composition.

Comment: I'm sorry kinda new to java, I'm trying to develop an appointment management program as a college project, so I'm trying to seek for information.

Comment: Look at: [Difference between Inheritance and Composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399544/difference-between-inheritance-and-composition) which may be a duplicate of your question since the answers answer and solve your problem.

Comment: Oh I see, so what I've been trying is pointless. Can you send me any sort of link that would help me understand how to procceed when it's a "has-a/several" relationship? And what does the term composition stand for in this context? Sorry, I'm not a native speaker, nor heard the term before.

Comment: "Composition" is just a fancy programmer word for "an instance of a class has a reference to another instance of a class". If you're declaring instance variables inside of your class, we say that you're *composing* those classes together.

Comment: Note that some of that code simply won't compile, some of this due to trivial spelling errors, as well as other errors. Best to fix these first before posting, if only to avoid unnecessary confusion. Your compiler should tell you where the problems are. Also, this line: `setHospital(name, email);` is in error.  If this were my code, I'd use separate setters and getters for each field, since `setHospital(...)` doesn't even make logical sense within the Hospital class, not as you're using it.

Comment: The spelling erros were my fault, since I've tried to translate it myself so it was easier for you to understand. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what you mean by "hospitals have several poles". I'm assuming your hierarchy looks like

```
public class Establishment {}

public class Hospital extends Establishment {}

public class Pole {}
```

If a hospital has a list of poles, then you can just query that list.

```
public class Hospital extends Establishment {
  private List<Pole> myPoles;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    String poleInformation = doSomethingWith(myPoles);
    return "Hospital with " + poleInformation;
  }

}
```

If the dependency is the other way round, then it's a bit trickier. That is, if a pole knows its hospital but a hospital doesn't know it's poles, then you can't get that information from just a hospital. If you have this.

```
public class Pole {
  private Hospital owner;
}
```

Then you'll need some sort of registration system. When a `Pole` is constructed, it will need to advertise itself to the hospital somehow. Maybe something like

```
public class Pole {
  private Hospital owner;

  public Pole(Hospital owner) {
    this.owner = owner;
    owner.addPole(this);
  }
}

public class Hospital extends Establishment {
  private List<Pole> myPoles;

  public void addPole(Pole newPole) {
    myPoles.add(newPole);
  }
}
```

And now we have the reverse dependency and can get that information from `Hospital` again. It all depends on how your data is stored.

Comment: Yeah, you got it right at first try. I'm confused, as Pole is a private class, how can I get the information from them on my hospital class, with the arrayList?

Comment: What do you mean by "private class"? Do you mean that `Pole` is declared inside of `Hospital` as a nested or inner class that's not exposed? Or is it declared as `private class` somewhere else inaccessible to `Hospital`? If it's declared nested in `Hospital`, you can access whatever you like regardless of visibility modifier. If it's `private` somewhere else, then you can't even refer to the *name* `Pole`. I think it would help if you edit the original post with some code snippets of how these two classes are actually declared and what member variables they have.

Comment: Will do right away, thank you.