# Base class instance in inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, instances

Hope I'm not asking something that has been already answered in here.

If my class B inherits from class A, does `new B()` create two instances in heap where B instance contains pointer to A instance, or there will be created only one instance of B including A members?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/inheritance

Comment: Doesn't it suck when you ask a question, and someone gives you a link to the documentation where you have to figure it all out for your self... However this is the most efficient way to learn things

Comment: But I don't see how the article explains the question at all. The question is about *how* inheritance is actually implemented in *.NET* - as in how is the memory actually allocated and how does the derived instance access the base instance. It doesn't even have to do anything with C# even though it's tagged as such. At least that's how I understood the question.

Comment: @Freggar See my answer, the picture is taken from this article.

Comment: @cembo actually the point was there is a ton of articles on this topic on msdn alone, and its easily searchable. asking this sort of question wastes your own time

Comment: @TheGeneral ... sure, no problem, I was just curious about how is it actually implemented at lower level. I tried to find an answer but I just couldn't find anything. I just wanted to know what compiler does in case of chained inheritance and so. Still learning :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Microsoft Inheritance article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/inheritance) :

This is how an object is represented in memory, given the Class Publication directly inherits the class Object.

[image]

So a inherited class is an object that contains all information about itself but also about its base class.

Comment: so in case of chained inheritance I will practically end up creating only one instance with multiple constructors each initializing their "own" members ?

Comment: @cembo well you will create one instance. When this instance will be created, one of it's constructors will be called. Before executing this constructor, it will call it's parent class' constructor. And so on until Object's constructor is called. Each constructor has the responsibility to initialize it's class members.

Comment: of course, thanks. Hope I'm not missing some clue in here, but it still puzzles me why constructor is part of an instance in memory (as I can see in your diagram) if it's used only once for members' initialization. Besides this description for this diagram says that it illustrates relationship between two classes not structure of instance in heap ...

Comment: @cembo A constructor is nothing else than a method. Actually the methods of a Type are not copied for each instance. Each instance owns a reference pointing to where the Type's methods are located. See https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20481/NET-Type-Internals-From-a-Microsoft-CLR-Perspecti , section Memory Layout.

Answer (score 4):

It will create one instance of B, and that B is also an A.

Comment: ["Is A" vs. "Has A"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263355/is-a-vs-has-a-which-one-is-better).

Comment: @Ferdinand Swaters, What do you mean by `B` is also an `A` ?

Comment: You can use the instance everywhere where an A is expected.

Answer (score 1):

it will create B instance that (because of inheritance) already include A members, if i understood your question well

Answer (score 1):

It creates one instance and you can access all the members of both A and B on that instance. As stated A is of type B as well. I imagine that in the low level code there probably exists a pointer to A.